# is there any example where i can see how to include a beneath secret auth in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to write_full a pandas dataframe from a jupyter notebook that deployed online to a beneath table, every time the notebook runs from a different compute instans so he ask to authorization, is there any example where i can skip the auth or even see how to include a beneath secret auth in a jupyter notebook?

> this is the df storing code

`````
await beneath.write_full(
 table_path="user/project/table",
 records=df,
 description="The results of the RFM Model")````
`````

Answer (score 0):

its resolved
if you set the the environment variable BENEATH_SECRET, the library will detect it. Alternatively, you can specify a secret when you initialize the client: client = beneath.Client(secret="INSERT_HERE") (reference:  https://python.docs.beneath.dev/client.html)